# NextJS - Categories (Tags) - Dynamic Pages

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js with Static Site Generation, and I've created a category (tags) component as shown below:

```js
import Link from "next/link";

export default function CategorySection({ categories }) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ContentWrapper>
        <CategoryWrapper>
          {categories.map((category) => {
            return (
              <>
                {category.contentfulMetadata.tags.map((tag) => {
                  return (
                    <Link href={`/articles/categories/${tag.id}`}>
                      <Categories>{tag.name}</Categories>
                    </Link>
                  );
                })}
              </>
            );
          })}
        </CategoryWrapper>
      </ContentWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

I would like to be able to create dynamic pages for all tags and show articles only related to the tag.

I have created my [slug].jsx file at the following location: /pages/articles/categories/[slug].jsx

[slug].jsx file below:

```js
import { getArticles, getArticle } from "../../../utils/contentful";

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const data = await getArticles();

  return {
    paths: data.articleCollection.items.map((article) => ({
      params: { slug: article.contentfulMetadata.tags.id },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const data = await getArticle(context.params.slug);

  return {
    props: { article: data.articleCollection.items[0] },
  };
}

export default function Category({ article }) {
  return <h1>{article.contentfulMetadata.tags.name}</h1>;
}
```

I get the following error when navigation by using the tags on my articles page:

*Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /articles/categories/[slug]*

How can I get it to create dynamic pages using the tags?

Comment: not pass a number for slug use .toString()

Comment: I tried .toString() but it says it's undefined.

Comment: where ? , "article.contentfulMetadata.tags.id" is a number ?

Comment: @MathiasRiisSørensen If `article.contentfulMetadata.tags.id` is undefined you shouldn't be generating a path for it. Make sure that value is valid before adding a path for it in `getStaticPaths`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. When I'm using GraphiQL I'm able to query for contentfulMetadata.tags.id, which is also used on the article cards that I have on the articles page. The id output characters (string) and not numbers.

Comment: When I click on a tag it navigates to a page with the id in the end like so:
http://localhost:3000/articles/categories/graphics

graphics is one of the tags.

Answer (score 1):

> Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /articles/categories/[slug]

In your getStaticPaths you need to convert slug to string.

```
params: { slug: article.contentfulMetadata.tags.id.toString() }
```

Comment: Hi, 

When I do that I get the following error message: 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"

Comment: And when you console.log(article.contentfulMetadata.tags.id) what do you have ?

Comment: It outputs an array with the tags that I currently have.

Comment: so that the problem you can't convert an array to a string you need to iterate article.contentfulMetadata.tags.id

Comment: @MathiasRiisSørensen show me the result of console.log(article.contentfulMetadata.tags.id) please

Comment: contenfulMetadata: Object tags: Array {name: "Design", id: "design"} and the same for two other tags.

Comment: i think is  params: { slug: article.contentfulMetadata.tags[0].id }

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the suggestion :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232166/discussion-between-daphaz-and-mathias-riis-sorensen).